# Complex number question

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

For any complex numbers  $z_1, z_2$, is the quantity $S$: $$
S = 4 \left(| z_1|^6 + |z_2 |^6\right ) + 4 |z_1|^3 |z_2 |^3 + \left(2 |z_1|^2\times \overline{z_1}^2\times z_2^2\right) + \left(2 |z_2|^2\times \overline{z_2}^2\times z_1^2 \right)$$ always real and nonnegative?

Here overline means the complex conjugate.

Comment: $S$ is real iff $S = \bar{S}$.

Comment: what if $z_1=1$ and $z_2 = 1+i$? The imaginary part is $4$.

Comment: It looks like $S$ will be real when $|z_1|=|z_2|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only part we need to check is $2\left|z_1\right|^2\,\bar{z}_1^2\,z_2^2 + 2\left|z_2\right|^2\,\bar{z}_2^2\,z_1^2$. Its two summands clearly have opposite argument (polar angles), but different moduli (radii) whenever $\left|z_1\right|\neq\left|z_2\right|$. Therefore the imaginary part of $S$ will be nonzero whenever $\left|z_1\right|\neq\left|z_2\right|$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint for the question "Is $S$ always real":

What is $\overline{S}$?